# Object from an HTML list

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What is the suggested way to solve this issue?

I have a HTML list like so:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="img1.jpg" alt="Image One" /></li>
  <li><img src="img2.jpg" alt="Image Two" /></li>
  <li><img src="img3.jpg" alt="Image Three" /></li>
</ul>
```

and I'd like to convert this data to an object, something like:

```
{
    images: {
        1: {
            src: "img1.jpg",
            alt: "Image One"
        },
        2: {
            src: "img2.jpg",
            title: "Image Two"
        },
        3: {
            src: "img3.jpg",
            title: "Image Three"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your example isn't actually valid JSON

Comment: It might not be valid JSON, but it *is* a valid object literal.  (if you add braces around it.)

Comment: Would you prefer a general solution? For example, what if the 'JSONed' nodes had nodes of their own?

Comment: That would be great as nodes having nodes of their own would be possible and very useful.

Comment: @AdamNuttall Ok. JQuery is probably your best bet for that type of functionality. Out of curiosity, what are you ultimately trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

I explained how it works in the comments.

Please tell me if there's anything wrong with the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <style>
            </style>

    </head>
    <body>


        <ul id="ul">
            <li><img src="img1.jpg" alt="Image One" /></li>
            <li><img src="img2.jpg" alt="Image Two" /></li>
            <li><img src="img3.jpg" alt="Image Three" /></li>
        </ul>


        <script>

            //Get the element that contains the image nodes
            var ul = document.getElementById("ul");

            //create a new 'images' object
            var images = {};


            //Note: this function call returns the image nodes in the order
            //they appear in the ul element. If an li node has 2 images, or no 
            //images, this method of retrieval may not suit your liking.
            var imgNodes = ul.getElementsByTagName("img");


            //Loop through all the image nodes
            for(var i = 0, l = imgNodes.length; i < l; i++) {

                //Add a new object to the images object
                images[i+1+""] = {

                    //getAttribute is a safe way to retrieve the attributes of a node
                    src :   imgNodes[i].getAttribute("src"),
                    alt :   imgNodes[i].getAttribute("alt")

                };

            }

            //Spit it out in the console to make sure it's good.
            console.log(images);


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I'll dig into it a little bit more before I mark it as solved but I've just given it a quick run through and it looks like it might do just what I'm after. It's very generous that you give away your time answering questions like this! Good man!

Comment: This code is very specific to your needs; it would require tweaking if you wanted it to do other similar things. I hate to say it, but you may want to consider using a framework like JQuery if you need to do this sort of thing often.

Answer (score 1):

look at jQuery's .map()

http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: jQuery is probably the most concise solution and it's not unreasonable to recommend that the poster use it.

Comment: @benalpert `jQuery` is `JavaScript` - it is better to understand how to construct structures in a given language than to abuse it through a framework

Comment: @Xander Lol, you're not helping this guy at all... he clearly wants to get data from html objects and place them into an array. jQuery is the simplest way to do that.